# 2011 Moderator Election begins shortly

Tags: discussion, election

In case anyone missed the [announcement](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/moderator-messages/) on the Stack Overflow Blog, the moderator elections are scheduled to begin on the 14th February.

**The election process**

The best way to get an idea of the election process is to check out another SE site. For example, here's the [election page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election/1) for the programmers SE site.

**What does a moderator do?**

There's some general guidance on being a moderator at the top of the programmers election [page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election/1). If you already visit the site almost every day, answer, edit and re-tag questions as appropriate, participate in meta when necessary, and vote to close/delete, then being a moderator will involve little extra work.

This site has never -- [touch wood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knocking_on_wood) -- had a problem with difficult users. We get the occasional SPAM message, but even that's fairly rare.

Others mods - feel free to add or edit this post.

Comment: what does that entail? I am pretty new to this, so maybe there is some link with detailed description how this works?

Comment: @mpiktas Does my update help?

Comment: splendidly! :)